# make my application visible for all network users

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I'm new to ReactJS. I have developed an app consisting of a table with several columns and I have been successful in rendering my application on localhost. My front-end is accessible from `http://localhost:3000` and back-end from `http://localhost:8000`. I'm using MongoDB as database.

Now I want to make it possible for my network users to see my app, therefore I run my code on a windows server whose IP is `10.68.10.20`. Now when my network users open `http://10.68.10.20/3000` on their PCs or laptops, they are able to see my application (and the table itself), but the content of my table (the content of the database) is not visible for them.

I see this error in the console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users?search=. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

So what's wrong? What changes should I make in my app to be visible for network users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error message, your app is attempting to make a request to `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users?search=.`. Probably because your front-end has `http://localhost:8000` back-end address hardcoded somewhere. Make sure that your backend is available on port `8000` to your network users at `http://10.68.10.20:3000`, and then change it in your app.

In production apps, such addresses would usually not be hard-coded into the app itself, but configured using [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) that would be applied at build/bundled step for a front-end application.

**Edit:** as you've specified that you're already using environment variables with `.env` files, what you typically do is:

- Create a different file (name something like `.prod.env`) to use for production deployment
- Specify all the environment variables that your app uses in it, so for example you would put `REACT_APP_API_URL=http://10.68.10.20:8000/api/v1` in it
- When you deploy your app for other users, use this file instead of the `.env` file you use for local development

This way you have an easy way to switch between configuration for local development and production, and can even launch the two environments simultaneously.

Comment: so you mean I should change `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users?search=..` to `http://10.68.10.20:8000/api/v1/users?search=..` in my code?

Comment: As a first step to solve your problem, yes. However, as you further work on the app, I suggest you change it to something like `${host}/api/v1/users?search=..` and then retrieve `host` from an environment variable so you don't have to change the code to deploy the app in a different environment.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if my question is obvious, but I have a `.env` file in my front-end folder and I have only entered this line: `REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000/api/v1` in this file. Then inside my other files I use the path like this: `const apiUrl = `${baseApiUrl}/users?search=${search}`. So should I change this method?

Comment: Thanks, I completely understood what you mean. By the way, I have a `.env` file in back-end containing for example `APP_URL=http://localhost:$APP_PORT` &`MONGO_HOST=localhost` & `MONGO_PORT=27017`, should I change these `localhost`s to `10.68.10.20` too? Right now, even if I haven't changed then, my app is visible for network users, so I don't know whether I should change these `localhost`s to `10.68.10.20` too?

Comment: I don't think you should change `MONGO_HOST`, as from the POV of your backend, your Mongo is still on `localhost`. Whether you should change `APP_URL` depends on how you actually use it on the backend, but it's probably a good idea. BTW, if you open the app deployed with `.prod.env` by opening `http://localhost:3000` it probably won't work because of same origin policy.

Comment: Right now, when i changed the `.env` file name containing `REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000/api/v1` to `.prod.env`. the content of the table is not displayed.

Comment: @free have you found the place in the app where it is configured to use the `.env` file? How does it know to load this file?